# MSAccess 2010 VBA Excel Process Not Terminating

Tags: excel, vba, process, ms-access-2010, orphan

I am using Window 7 SP1, and MS Office 2010. I am running queries in Access 2010, and writing the results in a report to Excel 2010, and noted that the instance of Excel does not terminate from the process listing. To make sure that it is not my code, I have stripped it down basics.

1. The following code opens and terminates Excel as expected:

   ```
   Public Sub Test()
       Dim strRptDirPath As String: strRptDirPath = "C:\Projects\WeeklyAlarms\Report\"
       Dim xlApp As Object
    '   Dim xlWkBk As Object
    '   Dim xlWkSht As Object
       Dim strRptTl As String: strRptTl = "Report Template.xls"
       Dim strRptSht As String: strRptSht = "Rpt"

       Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
           xlApp.Visible = False

   '    Set xlWkBk = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(strRptDir & strRptTl)
   '    Set xlWkSht = xlWkBk.Worksheets(strRptSht)
   '
   '        xlWkSht.Cells(1, 1).Value = "TEST 1"
   '        xlWkSht.Cells(2, 2).Value = "TEST 2"
   '        xlWkSht.Cells(3, 3).Value = "TEST 3"
   '
   '        xlWkBk.SaveAs (strRptDirPath & "TESTING.xls")
   '        xlWkBk.Close
           xlApp.Quit

   '    Set xlWkSht = Nothing
   '    Set xlWkBk = Nothing
       Set xlApp = Nothing

   End Sub
   ```
2. However, if i reference the workbook, the Excel process instance does not terminate. Searches through talk topics make references to the process terminating after a timeout 'ping' a period after Access closes - this is not the case here.

   ```
   Public Sub Test()
       Dim strRptDirPath As String: strRptDirPath = "C:\Projects\WeeklyAlarms\Report\"
       Dim xlApp As Object
       Dim xlWkBk As Object
   '   Dim xlWkSht As Object
       Dim strRptTl As String: strRptTl = "Report Template.xls"
       Dim strRptSht As String: strRptSht = "Rpt"

       Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
           xlApp.Visible = False

       Set xlWkBk = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(strRptDir & strRptTl)
   '    Set xlWkSht = xlWkBk.Worksheets(strRptSht)
   '
   '        xlWkSht.Cells(1, 1).Value = "TEST 1"
   '        xlWkSht.Cells(2, 2).Value = "TEST 2"
   '        xlWkSht.Cells(3, 3).Value = "TEST 3"

           xlWkBk.SaveAs (strRptDirPath & "TESTING.xls")
           xlWkBk.Close
           xlApp.Quit

   '   Set xlWkSht = Nothing
      Set xlWkBk = Nothing
      Set xlApp = Nothing

   End Sub
   ```

I have un-checked Microsoft Excel 14.0 Object library reference. I don't think i have made any global reference calls. I cant see what I am doing incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing everything after the `xlWkBk.SaveAs (strRptDirPath & "TESTING.xls")` line with:

```
If Not xlWkBk Is Nothing Then
    xlWkBk.Save
    xlWkBk.Close
    Set xlWkBk = Nothing
End If
If Not xlApp Is Nothing Then
    xlApp.Quit
    Set xlApp = Nothing
End If
```

Setting it up like this has ensured for me that everything closes as expected

Comment: thanks @Dane_l - i tried that, but an instance of Excel stays within the process listing

Comment: I presume you've cancelled the process, so you have no excel processes running, then you used this code after?

Comment: yes. End-Process-Tree for each Excel instance. If i open the Excel file created and the close it from within the Excel application, the process will terminate.  As it is implying that a reference is open, i tried to close it twice with [xlApp.ActiveWorkbook.Close] as well as [xlWkBk.Close], but received an error advising that there is no active connection

Comment: Ok, the only thing I would do then would be to watch the task manager process and step through the coding in segments to what is makiing it open two excel instances. I get the feeling there is a very small issue here...

Comment: There is only one EXCEL process in the Task Manager. I've tried it on another machine with the same specs - Win7SP1, MS Office 2010, and the EXCEL process terminates, but when opening the Excel file created - it brings up a file format warning.